# Getting Crash with Database is locked code 5 SQLITE_BUSY

Tags: android, sqlite

A crash is getting registered for few devices, with below logcat.

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5 SQLITE_BUSY)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:715)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:468)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:269)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:211)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:919)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:899)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:763)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:752)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:373)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
   at com.zingoy.app.getlink.GetLinkStoreDBHandler.addC2CStore(GetLinkStoreDBHandler.java:94)
   at com.zingoy.app.home.HomeActivity.lambda$setAllStores$8(HomeActivity.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Have gone through multiple solution but not getting what wrong is happening with my code.

Below is the code for using SQLite Database.

```
public void setAllStores(final AllStoreFetchListener listener) {
    if (DateUtil.isTimeMoreThanHours(mPreference.getAllStoresFetchedTime(), 24)) {
        new CommonApi().withAllStoreListener(response -> {
            try {
                if (response == null) return;
                if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(response.stores)) return;
                mPreference.setAllStoresFetchedTime();
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                new Thread(() -> {
                    new GetLinkStoreDBHandler(HomeActivity.this).addStore(response.stores);
                    this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            listener.onAllStoreFetched();
                        }
                    });
                }).start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).getStoreData();
    }
    if (DateUtil.isTimeMoreThanHours(mPreference.getC2CStoresFetchedTime(), 6)) {
        new SellerApi().withSellerStoreListener(response -> {
            try {
                if (response == null) return;
                if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(response.stores)) return;
                mPreference.setC2CStoresFetchedTime();
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                new Thread(() -> {
                    new GetLinkStoreDBHandler(HomeActivity.this).addC2CStore(response.stores);
                    this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            listener.onC2CStoreFetched();
                        }
                    });
                }).start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).getStoreData();
    }
}
```

This particular code is to create database instance and add the store to local database.

```
public class GetLinkStoreDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GetLinkStores";
private static final String TABLE_STORE = "Store";
private static final String TABLE_C2C_STORE = "SellerStore";

// StoreDbRows Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_STORE_ID = "storeId";
private static final String KEY_STORE_SLUG = "storeSlug";
private static final String KEY_STORE_NAME = "storeName";
private static final String KEY_STORE_LINK = "storeLink";
private static final String KEY_STORE_IMAGE_URL = "storeImageUrl";

public GetLinkStoreDBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_StoreDbRowS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STORE + "("
            + KEY_STORE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_STORE_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_STORE_LINK + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_STORE_IMAGE_URL + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_StoreDbRowS_TABLE);
    String CREATE_SELLER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_C2C_STORE + "("
            + KEY_STORE_SLUG + " TEXT," + KEY_STORE_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_STORE_IMAGE_URL + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SELLER_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    try {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STORE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_C2C_STORE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


// Adding new Store row
public void addStore(List<Store> getLinkStore) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        for (Store stores : getLinkStore) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_STORE_ID, stores.id);
            values.put(KEY_STORE_NAME, stores.name);
            values.put(KEY_STORE_LINK, stores.url);
            values.put(KEY_STORE_IMAGE_URL, stores.photoUrl);

            if (!isStoreAvailable(stores.id)) {
                // Inserting Row
                db.insert(TABLE_STORE, null, values);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage() == null) return;
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }
}
```

I have gone through solution which says multiple instances are getting called, i'm not getting where i can fix this.

Comment: My advice is to use https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: @IvanWooll Good Advice, Currently i'm looking for hotfix as users are getting affected due to this.